# how to use supabase RLS with "in" and "select" without having to provide unrestricted RLS access to the joined tables

Tags: postgresql, supabase, row-level-security, supabase-database

I am trying to set up simple RLS on my supabase tables. I enabled RLS on *all* tables, then added this policy to a table I wanted to select from:

```
(project_id IN ( SELECT projects.id FROM projects))
```

However, it always fails because the table projects also has RLS on.

In reality, the policies would be more complicated and involve multiple tables.

How do I work with RLS without having to expose all the tables required to make the RLS policy?

Comment: looks like i'll have to use security definer functions... will update if i figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out, turns out it's relatively simple but I'll post an answer for people coming across the same issues with no guidance.

Solution was to use `security definer functions` which can query RLS-protected tables without RLS penalties:

https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/postgres/row-level-security#use-security-definer-functions

https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#using-security-definer-functions

You can create a new schema, `private`, and add the functions you need using the SQL editor or the GUI. The function can take arguments, as shown in the postgres documentation, which also explains some other options:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html